# VS2015/ASP not updating iis express files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an issue which I believe is IIS Express related. I am making a Web App with ASP Web Forms(I know I should be using MVC, but for this project, Web Forms was specified as required). Whenever I build it opens the url http://localhost:53605 and loads the website. The problem is the copy is showing is old, this started happening yesterday, I haven't installed any updates to VS or Windows.

1. Things I have tried:
2. Disabling Chome Cache
3. Using another browser
4. Change the IIS Express build url (This works, for ONE build and then it's back to the same issue)
5. Delete the /bin & /debug folders

Does anyone have a solution to this? I can just change the build URL everytime, but anyone who had made an ASP Web App will you rebuild 100's of times a day...

Thanks

Comment: This can be related to IE also, check IE-Tools-Internet Options-General-Setting- Check for Newer Version of page , should not be never, it should automatically/every time.

Comment: It is already set to automatically

Comment: are you using Chome (not IE) to debug?

Comment: Yes I am using chrome

Comment: URL in my answer may help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If IE setting is OK, then set vs setting

```
Go to Tools-Options

Under Projects and solution ->
    Build and Run select "Always build" under "On Run, when projects are out of date"
```

For Chrome VS debug, [refer](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)